# loop.lenth ins jinja 2

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to format the display of tags for my blog.  I  can list tag1, tag2, tag3 etc...just fine. I even figured out how to eliminate the last comma with this:

```
{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
```

my question is... How do I a deal with "and"?

for example: tag1, tag2 and tag3.

here are the rules

if two tags = and with no comma separation.
if 3 or more tags = 2nd to last gets "and"
never a comma or and at the end of a list.

I was hoping I could create those display rules in jinja2 with something like this...

```
{% if loop.index == forloop.last - 1 %}and {% endif %}
```

of course, this code results in

> raise TemplateSyntaxError, "'if' statement improperly formatted"
>   TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted

I have a feeling someone is going to tell me do this in the app; not the template..  BUT please explain why...  Should I do this with a custom filter?

Comment: Are you applying any markup to the tags within the loop, or simply producing a plain-text string of names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended to [remove as much logic as possible from templates](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates) so you can focus on presentation and avoid adding points of failure to page rendering, but there are always borderline cases.

You will keep a much cleaner looking template if you define a custom filter similar to the built-in `join`.  Here's an example accepting a list of plain-text tag names and returning a string:

```
def join_tags(tags):
    if not tags:
        return '(no tags)'
    elif len(tags) == 1:
        return tags[0]
    else:
        return ', '.join(tags[:-1]) + ' and ' + tags[-1]

app.jinja_env.filters['join_tags'] = join_tags
```

Template usage:

```
{{ tags|join_tags }}
```

If you also add markup within your filter, you must apply the `safe` filter to the result so it will not be escaped.